# statvfs returns invalid information

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, disk-usage, ext4, ext3

My eMMC partition is ext4 formatted and has about 100MB. When I issue statvfs() on that partition, I get huge return value for f_blocks field of struct statvfs.

```
struct statvfs {
    unsigned long  f_bsize;    /* file system block size */
    unsigned long  f_frsize;   /* fragment size */
    fsblkcnt_t     f_blocks;   /* size of fs in f_frsize units */
    fsblkcnt_t     f_bfree;    /* # free blocks */
    fsblkcnt_t     f_bavail;   /* # free blocks for non-root */
    fsfilcnt_t     f_files;    /* # inodes */
    fsfilcnt_t     f_ffree;    /* # free inodes */
    fsfilcnt_t     f_favail;   /* # free inodes for non-root */
    unsigned long  f_fsid;     /* file system ID */
    unsigned long  f_flag;     /* mount flags */
    unsigned long  f_namemax;  /* maximum filename length */
  };
```

For your reference, above is the struct statvfs.

The value printed for the field f_blocks is 18446744073659310077 which is a huge one considering my partition is 100MB. df command also returns used and size of 16Z!

```
Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk2p4    16Z   16Z   79M 100% /data
```

Any idea what could be wrong? fsck on the partition succeeds. Not sure if there's a problem in the super block or what?  Below is the code for your reference.

```
if (statvfs_works ())
{
  struct statvfs vfsd;

  if (statvfs (file, &vfsd) < 0)
    return -1; 

  fsp->fsu_blocks = PROPAGATE_ALL_ONES (vfsd.f_blocks);
  ....
```

}

I am badly stuck and need to understand why the used and size field in df command returns value of 16Z. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Update with more info======================================

```
Output from /proc/partitions is as follows:  
179        3     102400 mmcblk2p4
```

strace reports the below output:

```
statfs64("/data", 88, {f_type="EXT2_SUPER_MAGIC", f_bsize=1024, f_blocks=18446744073659310077, f_bfree=87628, f_bavail=80460, f_files=25688, f_ffree=25189, f_fsid={-1446355608, 1063639410}, f_namelen=255, f_frsize=1024, f_flags=4128}) = 0
```

As can be seen f_blocks is a huge number. what could this mean? My kernel is 4.9.31. How do I get past this issue and make df report the correct output?

The output dumpe2fs returns the following

```
Block count:              102400
Reserved block count:     5120
Overhead blocks:          50343939
```

The overhead blocks is a huge number. What could this mean?

Regards

Comment: What does "dumpe2fs -h /dev/mmcblk2p4" show for the "blocks count" field? That is what ext4 considers the number of blocks in the filesystem, and should match the 100MB device size. What does "/proc/partitions" show? That is what the kernel thinks the device size is, based on what the driver+device report.

Comment: I have updated the details in the main summary itself. /proc/partitions reports correct value as can be seen. Via strace of df command, I see that the kernel reports incorrect value for f_blocks.

Comment: @LustreOne I converted your (flagged) answer into a comment, since it's requesting clarification of the OP.

Comment: The "overhead blocks" number _should_ be a fraction of "block count" that counts internal ext4 filesystem metadata, and is subtracted from the blocks count to compute the number of blocks that could be used in the filesystem.  It should definitely *not* be larger than the total number of blocks in the filesystem, and this is causing the blocks count to become negative (`102400 - 50343939 = 0xfffffffffd015ffd`) which appears as a huge positive number in this case).  I can't say for sure _why_ that happened, but did you try running `e2fsck -f`?  It is also possible to edit it with with debugfs.

Comment: Yes, i ran e2fsck it doesn't report any issues. I went through the kernel code in fs/ext4/super.c The following code is there                                                                    
         if (es->s_overhead_clusters)
  sbi->s_overhead = le32_to_cpu(es->s_overhead_clusters);
 else {
  err = ext4_calculate_overhead(sb);
  if (err)
   goto failed_mount_wq;
 }    any idea how the es->s_overhead_clusters are calculated?